# Ignore specific file when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any way to filter out specific files when running the debugger, specifically for C#? We have a logger class that intercepts calls between certain classes and logs them. It is very annoying that "Step Into" always goes through that file despite it not adding any useful information.

Is it possible to set a filter for files that should be ignored when running the debugger so that it is always skipped and the step goes to the next non-ignored file instead?

Comment: Seems like your are after `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`, but not sure what you mean by `file`.

Comment: Or `DebuggerHiddenAttribute`.  But I don't think you can apply it to an entire class or file, it only applies to functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can mark methods to be ignored by the debugger with `[DebuggerStepThrough]`. For example:

```
public class Logger
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void Log(string message);
}
```

Now if you try to step into this method, it will be skipped.